# What is the first moment of a measure?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I know what the first moment of a random variable is, however the paper I am reading refers to measures with "finite first moment", and I am unable to find a definition for this.

Thanks.

Comment: What space are these measures on? Is in on the reals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mu$ is a measure on $(\Omega,\sigma)$ then moments are defined:

$$\int_\Omega x^n d\mu(x)$$

Comment: The function $x^n$ has to be well defined and (generally real valued) for this to make sense. Usually, you have $(\Omega,\sigma) = (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and $\mu$ is a probability measure on that measure space. Then the moments of $\mu$ are the same as the moments of a random variable with distribution $\mu$.

Comment: @tkideneb of course, good point. Though you can extend further than just reals by different means. OP should specify. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Actually even when the function $x^n$ is well-defined, the value of $\int_{\Omega} x^n d\mu(x)$ is not always finite. Then if this intergal is finite, it is understood as $n$th moment of the measure $\mu$.